Printer problem: job done but no print
Please help
We are using zebra printer Printer Model : Zebra ZT230t
We are using auto printing method using the script

Its for label printing purpose
From EBS server file will be placed in print spool which we configured and script will automatically print the xml file
Here the issue is, lpstat -W completed showing completed and from the printer no print came
When we are giving normally without script print is coming
Script is working fine too

Could you please us to resolve the issue, if need more details please let us know

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release detail, so we don't have a starting point as to what software stack is involved; you've not said what program(s) you're printing from (how packaged etc) ...  You do mention detail around your procedures, but it's best if you provide full detail & assume we're not familiar with your system & apps.  A quick search on EBS server came up with a Amazon Cloud product; so this is a cloud system you're using on Amazon?  It's best if we're told

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! In addition to @guiverc 's comment, it would also be important to specify whether your printer is successfully printing other documents (e.g. a simple text document or a website). If this is the case, the problem would be related to the method you're describing, otherwise it could be a general problem with the printer driver.

Dear Thanks for your kind response,
And sorry for the inconvenience
Here we are using the script to print a file name with *.xml

We could able to print the file when we print by using lpstat command directly, but through script not working but script is all good as check.  The script is below:
if find /d05/printsh/printspool -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read; then
delimitert="-------"
lastfile=$(find /d05/printsh/printspool -type f -name '*.xml' -exec ls -t1 {} + | head -1)
printerselection=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//labels/@_PRINTERNAME)' $lastfile)
